# Incorrect tooltip display of text on tableau server

Tags: server, tooltip, tableau-api

I am using tableau server -  9.1.1 (9100.15.1013.2200) 64-bit. When I upload workbooks the tooltip is showing incorrect values (i.e. they are not the same as that in the workbook i have on my system). Why would that happen?
Is it because something is wrong with my workbook?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug in tableau server that has been fixed in 9.1.3 and successive versions. I faced the same issue and I usually single-click on the relevant chart and the tooltip updates to show correct information.

This is the answer I got from folks over at Tableau:

"It turns out that this particular issue was considered a high risk to the existing code to implement the fix. The code changes that were made in 9.1 made this fix less risky and so the developers were able to implement the resolution in 9.1.3. 9.2.2, and later versions.

The issue was reported by a handful of users, about 5 others, due to the high risk in the 9.0 branch if something went wrong it could potentially affect hundreds or thousands of users (you included). The decision was made in favor of the fix being implemented in 9.1 and 9.2."

Comment: I upgraded my workbook and our organization updated the server also. But we are still facing the same issue. -_-
But thanks for letting us know that you are aware and working on it!